# Are there CSV files or lookup table to correct for real north now and in the future?

Tags: csv, gps, embedded, lookup, compass

I am currently working on placing a compass on an embedded microchip PIC32 family device I am working on.

The compass is made in another part of the world and once assembled I want to be able to use it in other parts of the world without having to re-calibrate it every where I go.

The embedded device also has a GPS unit on it so I figured I should be able to adjust for the localised difference between real and magnetic north poles. If I had a look-up table the current GPS position can be used to calculate the angle off set and adjust the compass reading.

Does anyone know where I can source these?

(Unfortunately google related searches are now clogged with 9-11 conspiracy theories of flight planes being adjusted)

Comment: If you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Magnetic_Pole you see that this point is not at a fixed position, it's moving rather fast. Furtheron the magnetic poles should have switched long time ago, tho they say, a swich would last about 1,000 years. No one has experienced it so far. Will your software be prepared for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a python module, [geomag](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geomag/0.9.2015) that's worth a look.

`magnetic_declination_degrees = geomag.declination(latitude, longitude)`

```
>>> import geomag
>>> geomag.declination(-33, 151)
12.156567323514675
>>>
```

not csv, but easy-peasy.

Read the doc and you can adjust the model for date.

Edit:
If the embedded system runs [gpsd](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/), this [gps3 client](https://github.com/wadda/gps3) can fetch lat/lon automagically.

```
import time
import gps3
import geomag

the_connection = gps3.GPSDSocket() 
the_fix = gps3.Fix()

try:
    for new_data in the_connection:
        if new_data:
            the_fix.refresh(new_data)
        if not isinstance(the_fix.TPV['lat'], str):  # non-string lat is a determinate of when data is 'valid'
            latitude = the_fix.TPV['lat']
            longitude = the_fix.TPV['lon']  
            magnetic_declination_degrees = geomag.declination(latitude, longitude)
            print(magnetic_declination_degrees)
        time.sleep(5)
except Exception as error:
    print('Magnetic Declination is sick: ', error)
```

Edit: Here's a csv;-) Change the numerals in the range(s) for the granularity you want.

```
import geomag

for latitude in range(-60, 60, 10):
    for longitude in range(-180, 170, 10):
        magnetic_declination_degrees = geomag.declination(latitude, longitude)
        print(latitude, ',', longitude, ',', magnetic_declination_degrees)
```

Comment: Hi thanks Nodak, that looks very helpful and can always be used to make my own look-up table/csv file - though this might prove to be impractical. I won't be able to use this directly as the embedded system is a microchip PIC device which is running a C RTOS.

Comment: @Luke, I had just made the edit before learning about the PIC.  I'm sure you'll figure out something.

Comment: @Luke, You can make it pretty.

Comment: A warning, it appears the geomag module hasn't been updated to newer versions of WMM and is still using the 2015 model (writing this as of March 2021). Which means that using the geomag module will most likely provide incorrect declination values!

Answer (score 2):

NGDC (National Geophysical Data Center) publishes a World Magnetic Model (C code & data) that given a location & date returns field intensity and direction vectors.
http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/soft.shtml

The WMM data is republished every five years. Using the current WMM2015 data after 2020 will return valid but not as accurate results.